# Using ImageMagick in PHP to Recolor certain luminance values

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm having some trouble exporting the color values of a an equalized image, in order to recolor those equalized areas of grey.

```
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));  
$imagick->modulateImage(100,0,100);             
$imagick->quantizeImage(                        
    13,
    Imagick::COLORSPACE_TRANSPARENT,
    0,
    true,                                       
    false
);
```

This results in a greyscale image created by 13 different luminance levels. Now, what I can't understand how to do is to export the colors of the 13 luminance levels to an array, in order to recolor them using `opaquePaintImage`.

Right now I'm just recoloring RGBA values, which is not as accurate as I would like.

Please also note, that I'm also interested in how to recolor a *range* of RGBA values. As in, recolor 230-255 to red, recolor 210-230 to orange, etc.

That would be even better, almost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In ImageMagick, there is a -fuzz XX% to allow a range of values (some percent tolerance about some particular color. See the fuzz option in OpaquePaintImage at https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.opaquepaintimage.php

In Imagemagick, there is -unique-colors that lists one of every color in the image. See UniqueImageColors at https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.uniqueimagecolors.php